# Why does the phonon displacement have an overall factor of $i$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, second-quantization, phonons

I'm going through Mahan's book on Many Body Physics, and I'm a bit confused about one of his claims.  First he expresses the position of an atom as
$$\textbf{R}=\textbf{R}_{i}^{(0)}+\textbf{Q}_i$$
where $\textbf{R}_{i}^{(0)}$ is the equilibrium position and $\textbf{Q}_i$ is the displacement from equilibrium.  Based on the position operator for the $1D$ chain in $k$-space
$$x_l(t)=\sum_{k}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2mN\omega_k}}e^{ikal}(a_ke^{-i\omega_kt}+a_{-k}^\dagger e^{i\omega_kt})$$
he gives the $3D$ Ansatz as
$$\textbf{Q}_i=i\sum_{k,\lambda}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2MN\omega_{\textbf{k}\lambda}}}\xi_{\textbf{k},\lambda}(a_{\textbf{k},\lambda}e^{-i\omega_{\textbf{k}\lambda}t}+a_{-\textbf{k},\lambda}^{\dagger}e^{i\omega_{\textbf{k}\lambda}t})e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{R}_i^{(0)}}$$
He then states that the factor of $i$ is to make sure that $\textbf{Q}_i^\dagger=\textbf{Q}_i$.  I don't see how this is the case, since the term in brackets should be real and multiplying a phase by $i$ simply rotates it by $\pi/2$.  He does talk about taking the Hermitian conjugate and mapping $\textbf{k}\mapsto-\textbf{k}$, which for his Ansatz with the factor of $i$ gives an overall negative sign, but it still doesn't show how it is real (since the overall negative sign comes from the factor of $i$ he introduced!).  My only explanation is that he starts from the assumption that $-\xi_{-\textbf{k},\lambda}=\xi_{\textbf{k},\lambda}^*$, which he justifies using physical constraints, but since this comes after his Ansatz the reasoning seems incredibly circular.  Is the factor of $i$ to cancel out the negative sign from the polarisation vector?